# A solution of the Laplace equation that is compactly supported or vanishes at $\infty$ or near the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the Laplace equation 
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\Delta u =0 
\end{equation}
 on a bounded smooth domain (or the whole space).
Does there exist a solution for the Laplace equation that is compactly supported 
or vanishes near the boundary (or at $\infty$) ?

Comment: Not unless $u=0$ throughout the domain, by the maximum principle (alternatively harmonic functions are analytic so if they vanish on an open set then they're identically zero).

Comment: @Jose27 harmonic functions need not be analytic; e.g. $\bar {z}$.

Comment: If u is harmonic on $\mathbb C$ and vanishes at $\infty$ then it is bounded and there is an entire function whose real part is u. It follows that $e^{f}$ is a bounded entire function, hence a constant. This implies that f is itself a constant. So is its real part and hence $u \equiv 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about weak solutions ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Depends if you are in the complex or real case. Every harmonic real-valued function is real-analytic.

Comment: By elliptic regularity, weak solutions of $\Delta u =0$ are smooth, and hence classical solutions, so nothing changes with weak solutions.

Comment: @Kavi: I should have said real analytic.

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly, the answer is yes, at least for $n=2$ and on the whole space $\Bbb R^2\equiv \Bbb C$. Consider the following function indeed
$$
u(x,y)= \Re \exp\big({z^{-4}}\big)=\Re \exp\big({(re^{i\theta})}^{-4}\big).$$

As the real part of a holomorphic function on a connected domain, it is harmonic: nevertheless

1. it vanishes at the limit for $(x,y)$ going to $\infty$ along any path, and
2. it does not even define a distribution in any neighborhood of $0\in\Bbb C$

**Notes**

- This example is taken from the exercise book [1], chapter 2, p. 191.
- The reason that fooled the authors of the comments to the OP (and many more) is that they implicitly assumed that all harmonic functions are locally bounded and/or continuous and/or integrable (as weak solutions are).
- Perhaps $u(x,y)$ maybe used to produce a compactly supported harmonic function by taking its trace on the boundary of the unit disk $\Bbb D=\{z\in\Bbb C\mid |z|\le 1\}$ and then solve the exterior Dirichet problem for the Laplace equation on the plane. Said $u_e(x,y)$ the harmonic function found in this way, the function
  $$
  u_c(x,y)= u(x,y)-u_e(x,y)
  $$
  should be harmonic, discontinuous and compactly supported (obviously it is necessary to check this).

**Reference**

[1] Biler, P., Nadzieja, T. *Problems and Examples in Differential Equations*, Pure and Applied Mathematics 164, New York:Marcel Dekker, Inc., ISBN: 0-8247-8637-8, viii+244 (1992), [MR1198886](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1198886), [Zbl 0760.34001](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0760.34001).